# Gulp - compile TypeScript but split stream before concatenation

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have no idea if this is possible. Say I have two sets of TypeScript source files I want to compile with Gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');

var appSource = "./app/**/*.ts";
var packageSource = "./mypackage/**/*.ts";

gulp.task("build", function() {
    return gulp.src([appSource, packageSource])
          .pipe(typescript())
});
```

I want to compile all of the TypeScript together, but then split the output based on the original sources so that I can concatenate them separately and end up with two files:

```
app.js
mypackage.js
```

Mypackage is kind of an extension to the main application, and may be lazily loaded at a later time, but the TypeScript compilation will only work with all of the source files together.

Answer (score 0):

> Mypackage is kind of an extension to the main application, and may be
>   lazily loaded at a later time, but the TypeScript compilation will
>   only work with all of the source files together.

It is not necessary to really compile them together. The reason why your compilation is working with all sources files together is because it is finding all the type definitions made in your main application, when it is building your "Mypackage".

The correct way to deal with this is to compile it in two steps.

1. Compile the main application and have typescript generate the declaration files.
2. Compile the "Mypackage" by using the type declaration created from the main application. This would allow typescript compiler to find all the types that it needs while compiling Mypackage.

Below code example shows a similar use case where I am compiling my scripts first and generating type declarations from them and then compiling my specs.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var merge = require('merge2');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('compilescripts', function () {
    var tsScriptsProject = ts.createProject('scripts/tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = tsScriptsProject.src('**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts(tsScriptsProject));
    return merge([
        tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('')),
        tsResult.js.pipe(sourcemaps.write()).pipe(gulp.dest(''))
    ]);
});

gulp.task('compilespecs', function () {
    var tsSpecProject = ts.createProject('spec/UnitTests/tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = tsSpecProject.src('**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts(tsSpecProject));
    return tsResult.pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});

gulp.task('compileall', function (done) {
    runSequence('compilescripts', 'compilespecs', done);
});
```

Below is the tsconfig.json for compiling my scripts.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outFile": "dev-build/scripts/typesharp.js",
        "target": "es5",
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    }
}
```